# Why are these SQL queries returning different results from the same data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I'm trying to use that is giving me the wrong info and I can't see how/why.

If I break them down into simple queries I get the number I expect.

Here is the query that's giving me trouble:

```
SELECT
    [# of HR Devices]   = COUNT(DISTINCT IIF((bom.[Commodity Code] IN ('002') AND [dbo].[fn_getFactoryStdCost]([ComponentPartID]) > 0 AND bom.[Qty] > 0),   bom.[Component Part #], NULL)),
    [Sum HR Devices]    = SUM(DISTINCT IIF((bom.[Commodity Code] IN ('002') AND [dbo].[fn_getFactoryStdCost]([ComponentPartID]) > 0 AND bom.[Qty] > 0), bom.[Qty], NULL))
FROM 
    bomBreakdown bom 
WHERE 
    [SourcePartID] = '5157'
```

I get the following results:

```
# of HR Devices | Sum HR Devices
----------------+---------------
      20        |     15
```

Now if I use simplified (ie longhand) queries like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM bomBreakdown 
WHERE [SourcePartID] = '5157' 
  AND [Commodity Code] IN ('002') 
  AND [dbo].[fn_getFactoryStdCost]([ComponentPartID]) > 0 
  AND [Qty] > 0

SELECT SUM([Qty])
FROM bomBreakdown 
WHERE [SourcePartID] = '5157' 
  AND [Commodity Code] IN ('002') 
  AND [dbo].[fn_getFactoryStdCost]([ComponentPartID]) > 0 
  AND [Qty] > 0
```

I get 41 and 61 which are the correct numbers.

Below is the data, with the StdCost added using the same function for reference.

I just can't figure out why I'm getting 20 and 15 with what should essentially be the same query.

I'm using:

- SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2070.41)
- SSMS v18.5

[image: bomBreakdown]

Comment: I just don't see a relationship between the queries, because one uses `DISTINCT` and the other two do not.  I can say that I have never used `SUM(DISTINCT)` for a real query -- only for exercises showing why it is a bad idea.

Comment: And if you want people to help you debug such a situation, consider providing the DDL/DML statements (i.e. temp tables with sample data) to create a [MRE]. Because not many people are going to type that in from an image no less (even using formatted text instead of an image will improve your chances).

Comment: @GordonLinoff OMG!  I've been staring at this code all freaking day and the DISTINCT just completely disappears.  That was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplified version and the original version are NOT the same.

1. The simplified versions does NOT have `DISTINCT`. When `DISTINCT` is present, values are summed AFTER a distinct value list is generated. This means the same value will be counted or summed only once. If the result of the simplified versions are what you need, remove `DISTINCT` from both `COUNT` and `SUM` in your original query.
2. The COUNT in the simplified version is not specifying a column. The difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(column)` is that the former returns the row count but the latter returns count of non-NULL rows for that column. You can run this simple example to see it. You'll see it returns `3, 2`

```
    CREATE TABLE Table1 (Col1 INT);
    
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1), (2), (NULL);
    SELECT count(*), count(Col1) FROM table1;
    
    DROP TABLE1
```

If the result of the simplified versions are what you need, then use a column that is guaranteed not to have any `NULL` value in your original query.

3. If the result of the simplified versions are correct, why not do this:

```
    SELECT 
        [# of HR Devices] = SUM([Qty])
        , [Sum HR Devices]  = COUNT(*)
    FROM bomBreakdown 
    WHERE
        [SourcePartID] = '5157' 
        AND [Commodity Code] IN ('002') 
        AND [dbo].[fn_getFactoryStdCost]([ComponentPartID]) > 0 
        AND [Qty] > 0
```